# Language of stack configurations of a pushdown automaton

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, context-free-languages

Consider a pushdown automaton $A$ with stack alphabet $\Gamma$. Let $L$ be the language on $\Gamma$ of the stack configurations encountered during accepting runs of $A$. Is $L$ a context-free language?

Preliminary observations:

- $L$ is prefix-closed (any prefix of $L$ is in $L$)
- Using Bar-Hillel's lemma, pumping on the context-free language amounts to pumping on the stack language like a regular language. Hence, $L$ can be pumped as a regular language.

Comment: The stack language of a PDA is a regular language.

Comment: See [Context-Free Languages and Pushdown Automata](http://www.liafa.jussieu.fr/~carton/Enseignement/Complexite/ENS/Articles/cflpda.ps), Theorem 5.3 for the proof.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi The link is broken. Could you please provide a new link or the citation if it is a paper?